# Highlight TableView Cell's TextLabel text colour

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using a popover tableview in my project. I want to change the tableview cell's text colour from grey to red on selection. And i also want the highlighted color to remain red when the popover tableview is loaded next time like left menu selection. Need help to do this. I have provided the code for the popover tableview.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView === tableViewPopOver {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = FeedFilter.allValues[indexPath.row].rawValue
      if indexSelected == indexPath.row {
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
      } else {
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
      }

        //cell.selectionStyle = .None
        return cell
    }


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kDreamFeedTableViewCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DreamFeedTableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .None

    let dream = self.arrayDreams[indexPath.row]
    cell.dream = dream
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if tableView === tableViewPopOver {
        //tableViewPopOver?.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.textLabel?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor.redColor()
        //selectedIndexPath = indexPath.row

        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath.init(forRow: indexSelected, inSection: 0))
        cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        let cell2 = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell2?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        indexSelected = indexPath.row

        self.popover.dismiss()
        NRLoader.showLoader()
        self.searchDreams(true)
    }

    else { // dream feed tableview

        tableView .deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
        let dream = self.arrayDreams[indexPath.row]

        if !isValidUser(dream.user) {
            return
        }

        if isCurrentUser(dream.user)
        {
            self.pushToUserDreamViewControllerForDream(dream)
        }
        else
        {
            tableView .deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
            self.pushToFeedDetailViewControllerForDream(dream)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a problem with your code relate to `tableViewPopOver`. If you set selection style is `.None`. You can't select cell.

With your problem I can suggest for you two way to resolve:

1. If you want use `cell.textLabel?.highlightedTextColor` you will have face a problem: background of cell will be grey or blue depend on  style selection you select. If you can accept it. You can implement like this:

   You create a variable to hold a cell selected. Maybe it is `int` value like `var indexSelected = 3`. And when you implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you should implement like this:

   ```
   cell.textLabel?.text = FeedFilter.allValues[indexPath.row].rawValue
   cell.textLabel?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor.redColor()
   if indexPath.row == indexSelected {
       tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated:true, scrollPosition: .None)
   }
   return cell
   ```

   And in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you update `indexSelected`:

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

       indexSelected = indexPath.row //update selected row
   }
   ```
2. If you don't want cell background change color. You can choose this way. You should create variable like the way above. But in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you should implement:

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")//init cell it depend on your way create cell
       cell?.textLabel?.text = "Your text"

       if indexSelected == indexPath.row {
           cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
       } else {
           cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
       }


      return cell!
   }
   ```

and in `didSelectCellAtIndexPath` you should implement:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath.init(forRow: indexSelected, inSection: 0))
    cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    let cell2 = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell2?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    indexSelected = indexPath.row //update selected row
}
```

Here Demo: [Demo](https://github.com/vienvu89/DemoSelectionCell)

Hope this help!

Comment: this doesn't change anything

Comment: I think have problem with your code, wait me and I will give you a demo.

Comment: @GaneshKumar Check my edit answer, demo I have create two way, you just uncomment for seen it work.

Comment: i will check and let you know

Comment: My Problem is when i select  a row then the popover tableview will dismiss from the view. when i open it again the selected row should remain  in red. Here is the edited code.

Comment: So you should hold this value and save it on somewhere, maybe is singleton and when you present popup you get it and show to tableView

Comment: I have edited the code and provided above in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99769/discussion-between-ganesh-kumar-and-vien-vu).

Answer (score 0):

To change cell's text colour to red on selection you need to implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and change the cell text Color to red, but it will not stay red when you open it the next time. to handle that you need to have a member variable `selectedIndexPath`. So it will be something like this

```
var selectedIndexPath:NSIndexPath!
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        cell.textLabel?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor.redColor()
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        cell.textLabel?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        selectedIndexPath = nil
    }
}
```

And to load the table next time with the selected cell red text colour you need to add this line in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

**Cell**

```
cell.textLabel?.highlightedTextColor = indexPath == selectedIndexPath ?  UIColor.redColor() : UIColor.grayColor()
 }
```

Comment: i don't get your technique

Comment: you want to do some changes on cell when selected,right? you should do that by implementing the tableViewDelegate methods `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`.
You also want to preserve the change for the last selected cell when you open the table again. Then you should keep track of the the selected indexPath and check for it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to ask

Comment: i haven't found a solution yet